# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+1)z^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+1)z^n$

A) For which complex numbers $z$ does this series converge?

B) For those $z$, let $f(z)$ be the sum of the series and find $f(z)$.

C) Evaluate $f^{(5)}(0)$

**My approach for A:**

Using Ratio test, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n+1}{n+2}=0$$

Therefore, radius of convergence is zero. Is this the right approach?

**My approach for B**

I'm guessing we have to use Taylor's Theorem $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n$

**My Approach for C**

I'm thinking I have to take the fifth derivative of something here.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: The limit is $1$, not $0$. And you may recognize the given series as a derivative. Alternately, you can find an explicit formula for the partial sums, an bypass most theory.

Comment: The limit should be $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It's been years since I use ratio test. What did I do wrong?

Comment: When $n$ is big, $\frac{n+1}{n+2}$ is real close to $1$. If you want to be formal, divide top and bottom by $n$, and let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Note that $(n+1)/(n+2)=(1+1/n)/(1+2/n)$. Here both the numerator and the denominator tends to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the refresher colleagues. As for the rest, any clues here? Thanks again.

Comment: For b) think of (write them up) the first basic series you have learned about?

Comment: Did you try Cauchy's root test? $lim _{n -> \infty}| (n+1)^{1/n} z| < 1 $

Comment: For the second part, evaluate sum of an arithematic geometric progression and a geometric progression

Comment: Do we mean using the definition $\frac{1}{1-z}$?

Comment: @AD. do you mean $\frac{(n+1)}{1-z}$?

Comment: Note that your series is almost the term by term derivative of the standard series for $\frac{1}{1-z}$. The fit would be exact if we started at $n=0$. As it is, our series is $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}-1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas wow, how we get there?

Comment: The series for$\frac{1}{1-z}$ is familiar, it is $1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots$, absolutely convergent if $|z|\lt 1$. The term by term derivative is $1+2z+3z^2+4z^3+\cdots$. This is $1+ \text{our given series}$. But the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That was great thank you! And finally now we take the 5th derivative of this function and evaluate at $z=0$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. The proof requires some theoretical machinery, that guarantees that if $|z|\lt R$, where $R$ is the radius of convergence, then differentiation term by term yields the correct result.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So it's not wrong to differentiate 5 times right? Are we using taylor's theorem here?

Comment: Differentiating the explicit function we get $5$ times is not wrong, but it is not really necessary. You can instead differentiate the original expression you were given $5$ times, and set $z=0$. The only surviving term comes from differentiating $6x^{5}$ $5$ times, so the answer is $6!$.